# C++ bubble sort on vector using callback switch

Tags: c++, vector, bubble-sort

I have been trying to bubble sort a vector of int data which has been taken from a multi line text file. I have managed to seperate the data from the vector so that I have only the elements I need to sort, however I am having an issue getting the code to run using a vector. I am reusing code I have made earlier when sorting an array but can't seem to get it to play nicely with vectors.

**I have a seperate class for the sorting:**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Sorter {
public:
    int checker;

    //Callback function for bubble sort
    int compare(vector<int> a, vector<int> b) {
        //Do decending sort
        if (a > b) {
                return -1;
        }
        //Do ascending sort
        else {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    //Bubble sort - best case complexity omega(n)
    void bubbleSort(vector<int> &A, int n, int(*compare)(int, int)) {
        int i, j, temp;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
            for (j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) {
                if (compare(A[j], A[j + 1]) > 0) {
                    temp = A[j];
                    A[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**And the part of my main source file that calls it:**

```
Sorter sorter;
sorter.checker = inputVector[0];
vector<int> sortingVector;
cout << inputVector.size() << endl;
for (int i = 3; i <= inputVector[2]; i++) {
    sortingVector.push_back(inputVector[i]);

}

sorter.bubbleSort(sortingVector, inputVector[2], sorter.compare());
```

I'm getting the error: no suitable conversion function from "std::vector<int, std::allocator>" to "int" exists. This makes me think I either:

1. Can't use vectors or,
2. I have converted it to the wrong data type.

If anyone could help me work this out that would be amazing. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have a * below? Did you mean to use '&' to pass as a reference?
void bubbleSort(vector<int>* A, int n, int(*compare)(int, int))

Comment: @revelationnow Yes I've managed to fix that up :) Only thing I'm having trouble with now is an error from  sorter.compare(). Giving me this: argument of type "int" is incompatible with parameter of type "int (*)(int, int)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your compilation error is because you have *called* the comparison function with no arguments, and not passed it as a parameter.

You also have the issue that a non-static member function requires a `Sorter` (which `this` will point to).

The parameters of the comparison function need to be elements of the vector.

I would advise not using a class to hold free functions

```
int compare(int a, int b) {
    if (a > b) {
            return -1;
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
}

void bubbleSort(vector<int> &A, int(*compare)(int, int)) {
    for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < A.size() - 1; j++) {
            if (compare(A[j], A[j + 1]) > 0) {
                std::swap(A[j], A[j + 1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which you call as:

```
bubbleSort(sortingVector, compare);
```

Aside: if you were to use `std::sort`, you wouldn't need to copy from `inputVector` to sortingVector`

```
if (ascending) {
    std::sort(inputVector.begin() + 3, inputVector.end(), std::less<int>{});
} else {
    std::sort(inputVector.begin() + 3, inputVector.end(), std::greater<int>{});
}
```

Comment: Yeah ideally I would use std::sort, unfortunately I have to apply different sorting functions based on what input I get from the file. The first line of the file gives a 1 or 0 which I need to use make the program decide if it should sort in ascending / descending. Then I have to make a function for best case / worst case complexity. You and Dev have helped me a heap though, so thanks a lot :)

Comment: You can absolutely use `std::sort` and choose ascending or descending. Your current implementation *doesn't* choose between them.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the bubble sort function for optimization.

```
int compare(int a, int b) {
    //Do decending sort
    if (a > b) {
            return -1;
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
}
void bubbleSort(vector<int> &A, int n) {
    int temp;
    bool exe=false;
    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
            exe=false;
        for(int j=0;j<n-1-i;j++){
            if(compare(A[j],A[j+1]) >   0){
                temp=A[j];
                A[j]=A[j+1];
                A[j+1]=temp;
                exe=true;
            }
        }
        if(exe==false)
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to pass compare function to it u can reference it directly and don't pass n use size method like n=A.size() to get the length.The above bubble sort sorts in decending order modify as u wish.Hope it helps : )

Comment: for me it works if u have other problems comment them down.

Comment: Almost got it to work, just getting this issue "An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal" at the `code if (compare(A[j], A[j + 1]) > 0) ` line

Comment: @DevParzival This is clearly a learning exercise. Inlining the comparison doesn't let you use the same function for both ascending and descending sorts

Comment: @Caleth u are write . Above compare if for sorting in descending order only.

Comment: @BobFisher make compare as static and now call bubbleSort(v,v.size(),Sorter::compare); it will work